# Why is the linespread factor as it is?

Tags: line-spacing

The blog post [Quick note on line spacing](http://texblog.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/quick-note-on-line-spacing/) discusses line spacing and it says

> To change the line spacing for the entire document, you can use the
>   `linespread` command in your preamble:
>
> ```
> \linespread{<factor>}
> ```
>
> The factor is somewhat confusing. For double-spacing you have to use
>   1.6 and for one-and-a-half spacing 1.3. Not very intuitive, but I'm
>   sure there is a reason for it.

This unintuitive factor triggered my curiosity. What is the reason for it being as it is?

<sub>This question is just motivated by my curiosity and I have no practical reason for asking it. Feel free to close it if it's inappropriate or see at as post in the same vein as [\nothing, \varnothing and \emptyset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28493/nothing-varnothing-and-emptyset) in that it asks about history or some design decision.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps not an exact duplicate, but surely of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/what-does-double-spacing-mean

Comment: There's no official definition of "double spaced". Pick what is less displeasing ("more pleasing" would be an oxymoron).

Comment: In my [previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/what-does-double-spacing-mean), there may be 3 different definitions of "double-spacing". `setspace` package uses a different one other than MS Word, Ooo Write, etc.

Comment: I like curiosity questions. There should be an extra tag for it :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

With the LaTeX standard classes (`article`, `book`, and `report`) and no class options added, `\normalsize` results in a font size (size of the largest glyphs in a font -- typically, braces) of `10pt` and a `\baselineskip` (vertical skip between the base lines of two successive lines of type) of `12pt`. The ratio between font size and `\baselineskip` is 1.2.

The `linespread` command (which must be issued in the document preamble) may be used to change the `\baselineskip` without changing the font size.

A possible definition of `\onehalfspacing` and `\doublespacing` is that the ratio between font size and `\baselineskip` should be 1.5 resp. 2. Because the "basic" ratio for `10pt` is 1.2, a multiplier of 1.25 and (approximately) 1.667 has to be applied -- and this is basically what the `setspace` package  does. ("Basically" because it retains the ratio of 1.2 for footnotes and the like.)

The statement *"For double-spacing you have to use 1.6 and for one-and-a-half spacing 1.3"* amounts to either a rounding error, or being confused, or both.

Comment: If `\linespread` is a command for changing `\baselineskip`, wouldn't it be easier to just change `\baselineskip`?

Comment: @Sverre No`\linespread` does not change (immediately) `\baselineskip`. What it does is to modify the `\baselinestretch` which impacts size changing commands or font selection comand (which are the ones which will change the `\baselineskip` and other things). Thus the `\linespread` effects persists across font size changes.

Answer (score 53):

Extending [lockstep's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30106/5764) to other document class options (like `11pt` and `12pt`) gives rise to the seemingly strange scaling factors used by the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace):

- `10pt` (already discussed)

  `setspace` defines the scaling factor to be `1.25` for `\onehalfspacing` and `1.667` for `\doublespacing`, since the "basic" ratio is `1.2` (`\normalfont` has a `\baselineskip` of `12pt`; see [`size10.clo`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo?view=co))
- `11pt`

  `setspace` defines the scaling factor to be `1.213` for `\onehalfspacing` and `1.618` for `\doublespacing`, since the "basic" ratio is `1.236` (`\normalfont` has a `\baselineskip` of `13.6pt`; see [`size11.clo`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo?view=co))
- `12pt`

  `setspace` defines the scaling factor to be `1.241` for `\onehalfspacing` and `1.655` for `\doublespacing`, since the "basic" ratio is `1.208` (`\normalfont` has a `\baselineskip` of `14.5pt`; see [`size12.clo`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo?view=co))

As such, in the following hypothetical situation, a scaling factor of `2.4` (that is, `\setstretch{2.4}`) would provide "triple spacing" in a document with normal font size of `16pt` and `\baselineskip` of `20pt`.

All scaling factors are rounded to 3 digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 4):

I recently tried to customize the line spacing in a [`ctex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ctex) document and this post served as one of my references. During my research, however, I found a mistake made by the [`setspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package.

To further extend [Werner’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30114/164314), I want to point out that [`setspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) has set both factors for an `11pt` article *wrong*, unfortunately.

We find in [`size11.clo`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo?view=co) that `\normalsize` is defined by

```
\@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13.6}%
```

The problem is that the “basic” ratio in `11pt` article is *not* `13.6/11` but rather `13.6/10.95` for [historical reasons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264639/164314). This implies that for `\onehalfspacing`, the factor should be around `1.2077205882`, *not* `1.213`; and for `\doublespacing`, the factor should be around `1.6102941176`, *not* `1.618`.

I have no idea why `article` inconsistently sets the body text leading/fontsize basic ratio to be `1.2`, `1.242` (*not* `1.236`) and `1.208` for `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt`, respectively.

Comment: Have reported your findings to https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/issues