# increase vertical space between lines

Tags: spacing, arrays

I want to increase the vertical space between each of the lines. I know you can use \arraystretch but i am struggling with the package.
here is my source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Express $0.\dot{3}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{3}$ \\
        then $10x=3.\dot{3}$ \\
        $10x-x=3.\dot{3}-0.\dot{3}$ \\
        $9x=3$ \\
        $9x=\frac{3}{9}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document
```

and the output:

[image: 1]

Comment: `\arraystretch` is for `array` and `tabular` purpose only.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Linespacing LaTeX for just a few lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122487/5764)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `setspace` package and, e.g. its `doublespace` environment, or if you want something more customised, the `spacing` environment, which has an argument, the value of `\baselinestretch`. Beware that doublespacing is *not*  the same as choosing `\baseline stretch=2`., as the example below demonstrates.

The setspace package defines 4 commands : `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing`, `doublespacing` and `\setstretch{#1}`, to be used in the preamble, and 4 environments, to be used in the body of the document: `\singlespace`, `\onehalfspace`, `doublespace` and `spacing{#1}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Express $0.\dot{3}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{3}$ \\
        then $10x=3.\dot{3}$ \\
        $10x-x=3.\dot{3}-0.\dot{3}$ \\
        $9x=3$ \\
        $9x=\frac{3}{9}$
\end{enumerate}


\verb+doublespace+: \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
\begin{doublespace}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Express $0.\dot{3}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{3}$ \\
        then $10x=3.\dot{3}$ \\
        $10x-x=3.\dot{3}-0.\dot{3}$ \\
        $9x=3$ \\
        $9x=\frac{3}{9}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{doublespace}


\verb+spacing{2}+:\vspace{-1.333\baselineskip}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Express $0.\dot{3}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{3}$ \\
        then $10x=3.\dot{3}$ \\
        $10x-x=3.\dot{3}-0.\dot{3}$ \\
        $9x=3$ \\
        $9x=\frac{3}{9}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{2em}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Express $0.\dot{3}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{3}$ \\
        then $10x=3.\dot{3}$ \\
        $10x-x=3.\dot{3}-0.\dot{3}$ \\
        $9x=3$ \\
        $9x=\frac{3}{9}$
\end{enumerate}}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Express $0.\dot{3}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{3}$ \\
        then $10x=3.\dot{3}$ \\
        $10x-x=3.\dot{3}-0.\dot{3}$ \\
        $9x=3$ \\
        $9x=\frac{3}{9}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```