# how to add vertical space between words and the underline effect?

Tags: spacing, soul, vertical, underline

I searched around here and did not find anything accurate to what I wanted. I would like to know other ways to increase the decrease in the space between underline and words as well as in this MWE below using [soul package](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul).

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
    \setul{10ex}{}

\begin{document}
BIRD BIRD \ul{JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ \\ JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ}
\end{document}
```

[image: Making space between words and underline with soul package.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `setspace` package, see here: [increase vertical space between lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180653/increase-vertical-space-between-lines). But I'm not sure to understand what you're asking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
I don't understand if you intend something like this:
\begin{spacing}{8}
\setul{10ex}{}
BIRD BIRD \ul{JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ}

\noindent\ul{JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ}
\end{spacing}

or something like this:
\begin{spacing}{4}
BIRD BIRD \ul{JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ}

\noindent\ul{JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @CarlaTex, I would like to have options to decrease or increase the distance between the word and the underline. It either increases or decreases the distance. The two examples above (both your example and mine) are what I want, but I would like to discover new ways of doing this. Thanks for listening.

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah The option to modify the distance between the underline and the words is `\setul{xxx}{}`, where you can set any length instead of `xxx`. The option to modify the distance between the lines of text is `\begin{spacing}{yyy}`, where you can set any number instead of `yyy`. Sorry, I don't know other methods.

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah You're welcome!