# Is there something between singlespace and onehalfspace?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

Is there anything between `singlespace` and `onehalfspace`?

The reason is that, when I use `singlespace` it seems to be very compact, while `onehalfspace` puts more space between lines than I would like it to.

Note these come from the [`setspace` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/setspace?lang=en).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. Using the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) with a `10pt` document font, a factor between `1.0` and `1.25` would lie "between" `\singlespacing` and `\onehalfspacing`. An idea of the appropriate spacing that is dependent on the default font size is available from [Why is the linespread factor as it is?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/5764).

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{setspace,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\singlespacing\lipsum[2]
\setstretch{1.125}\lipsum[2]% Line spread between \singlespacing and \onehalfspacing
\onehalfspacing\lipsum[2]
\doublespacing\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Note that [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) inserts a paragraph break at the end of every `\lipsum` by default, which is required to have different `\linespread` across paragraphs in the example.

Comment: thanks, how do you set it for the whole document? \setstretch{1.125} in the beginning?

Comment: @user3232: Yes, or use `\AtBeginDocument{\setstretch{1.125}}` in your document preamble (separating setup/structure from content).

Answer (score 6):

With the `setspace` package you can use the `spacing` environment with an optional argument containing the desired factor like this:

```
\begin{spacing}{1.25}
...
\end{spacing}
```

Comment: Curly braces or accolades are required for the argument: `\begin{spacing}{1.25}`