# Arithmetic operation in user-defined command

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I want to define a command to ease the font configuration as below:

```
\newcommand{\setfont}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont}
```

The new command `\setfont` takes two parameters: one is the size of the font, the other is the line space.

However, it is not convenient to specify the line spacing in point directly.
The more intuitive way is to set, e.g. two line spacing, or 1.5 line spacing.
So in my command I want to take the second parameter a scale factor.
The problem is how to apply the scale factor to the line spacing arguments?
With arithmetic operation or other workaround?

Comment: Have you considered the [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package as part of this command? It manages line spacing well.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for the hint. But I should set something in the `\fontsize` command, is `\newcommand{\setfont}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#1} \set_linespace_with_#2 \selectfont}` ok? Also, what if I want a 1.25 line spacing, I skip the document of the package, but didn't find the proper command :p.

Comment: Note that [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace)'s `\setstretch` factors are not to be interpreted verbatim. See [Why is the linespread factor as it is?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,lipsum,setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lmodern,lipsum,setspace}
\newcommand{\setfont}[2]{\setstretch{#2}\fontsize{#1}{#1}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\setfont{20}{1.5}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Note that `\fontsize` takes two arguments that do not necessarily have to be dimensions. As such, using a combination of scale factor and multiplication with a dimensions might not work as expected (haven't tested it). The [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) provides `\setstretch{<num>}` which helps, but also manages other things.

Also remember that line-spacing factors are not always what they seem to be. See [Why is the linespread factor as it is?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/5764)

Answer (score 2):

`TeX` can multiply dimensions as in `1.5\dimenregister`.  So what you can do is to assign #1 to a temp dimen register and multiply it.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\setfont[2]{\@tempdima=#1\fontsize{\@tempdima}{#2\@tempdima}%
  \selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setfont{25pt}{1.5} Test\\ test

\end{document}
```

P.S.  Dan in the comments suggested an enhancement that allows commands like `\setfont{25}{1.5}`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setfont[2]{\@defaultunits\@tempdima#1pt\relax\@nnil
   \fontsize{\@tempdima}{#2\@tempdima}\selectfont}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Just curious: What happens when the user supplies `\setfont{25}{1.5}`?

Comment: This will not work, of course.  It is possible to check whether the argument is numeric or a dimen, but for user defined commands a certain laziness in checking the input is expected.  Writing a package one should be more careful.

Comment: Latex has an internal command to cover this case. Using `\@defaultunits\@tempdima#1pt\relax\@nnil` instead of just `\@tempdima=#1` will allow both `\setfont{25}{1.5}` and `setfont{25pt}{1.5}` to work.