# Baselineskip not changed for footnotes

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,mathptmx}

%\baselineskip16pt

\begin{document}
\baselineskip16pt
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[3]}
\par\noindent\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

This code shows how setting `\baselineskip` for the document does not set it for footnotes, since the main text is set to have wider interline spacing, while the footnote text isn't. My question is: why is that?

PS While making this example, I bumped into another thing: the commented line of code, if uncommented, does absolutely nothing. That is, if I uncomment that and remove the other `\baselineskip16pt`, the baseline skip is not changed. Why does that happen?

Comment: Does `\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\begingroup\linespread{1.5}\oldfootnote{#1}\endgroup}` do what you want? You can change 1.5 to whatever you like.

Comment: You should act on `\baselinestretch` rather than setting `\baselineskip`. For this use `\linespread{1.3333}` in the preamble.

Comment: [Explanation of `\linespread`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30073/why-is-the-linespread-factor-as-it-is). But why is there such a difference? I mean, why is the `\baselineskip` set only for the "body of the document" and not for the footnotes?