# latex \fontsize{12}{18} equals to MS Word 12pt and its linespace 1.5?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, fontspec, line-spacing

I use \fontsize{12}{18} in latex for 12pt and its linespace 1.5 in MS Word. But I think not equals. Why? And what is correct option in \fontsize{?}{?} ?

Comment: See a combination of [Setting a document in MS Word-12pt (12bp)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34024/5764) (for font size setting) and [Why is the `\linespread` factor as it is?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/5764) (for the correct line spacing factor). You should use [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) to change the line spacing.