# how can we set some line spce at 2 and other at 1.5

Tags: line-spacing

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5 in,right=0.5 in,bottom=1 in,top=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\numberwithin{figure}{subsection}
\numberwithin{table}{subsection}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup{justification =raggedright, singleline check= false}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\section*{List Of Abbreviations}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\textbf{Abbreviation}&\textbf{Illustration}\\
LCD&Liquid Crystal Display\\
3D&Three Dimensional\\
VRD&Virtual Retinal Display \\
PDA&Personal Digital Assistant\\
RSD&Retinal Scan Display \\
LED&Light Emitting Diode\\
HD&High Defination\\
CRT&Cathode Ray Tube\\

\end{tabular} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagebreak


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\pagebreak


%\pagenumbering{roman}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\renewcommand{\thesection}
{\arabic{section}.}
    \section{INTRODUCTION}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\thesection}
{\arabic{section}}

        \paragraph*{}
Nowadays, advanced technologies are growing faster wherein each technology is renewed with implementation of new one. The current trending display technology most commonly used in gadgets such as tablets, smart phones, etc., is the touch-screen display, which will become outdated in the near future. Screenless display is the advanced display technology, which replaces the touch screen technology to resolve the problems and to make lives more comfortable. Therefore, this article is intended to give an idea of the screenless display, which transmits or displays the information without using a projector or the screen. By using this screenless display technology, we can display the images directly on the open space, human retina and also to the human brain.

\paragraph*{}
           During the year 2014, this display came into progress by the implementation of products like virtual reality headsets, retinal displays and holographic videos. Lack of space is the major drawback for most of the screen displays. This problem can be overcome by the use of screenless displays.

\paragraph*{} 
What is Screenless Display?
Screenless display is an interactive projection technology developed to solve the problems related to the device miniaturization of the modern communication technologies. The lack of space on screen based displays provides an opportunity for the development of screenless displays. As the name indicates screenless display has no screen and it can be defined as a display used to transmit any data such as pictures or videos without the help of screens.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please complete your example to a compilable one. Please have a also a look on the `setspace` package and its `singlespace`, `onehalfspace` and `doublespace` environments

Comment: Please state explicitly which parts of your document should be placed in `onehalfspacing` and `doublespacing` environments, respectively. Incidentally, what is the purpose of the three `\paragraph*{}` instructions?

Comment: Related: [Why is the linespread factor as it is?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/5764)

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify the low-level macro `\linespread` directly. Instead, load the `setspace` package and issue instructions such as `\setstretch{1.5}`, etc