# Package PDF specification "setspace – Set space between lines"

Tags: setspace

- Where I can find the PDF manual for `setspace` package?
- Or at least alternatives for this package to use within my LaTeX document?

Comment: `setspace` doesn't have a PDF documentation.  You can find a plain text documentation in the [`setspace.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/setspace/setspace.sty) from line 223 (`Usage`) onwards

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I suppose we could fix that....

Comment: Related: [Why is the linespread factor as it is?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/5764) - there is some discussion on setting the space between the lines.