# Maximizing number of words with constraints on number of characters and lines per inch

Tags: fonts, line-spacing

An organization has the following specs for submitted articles: (a) maximum of 15 characters per 2.5 cm (b) maximum of 6 lines per 2.5 cm (c) minimum font size of 10 (d) Computer Modern font (e) 2.5 cm margins. Assuming an ``average text'', how can I maximize the number of words per page with such constraints? It appears to me that with font size of 10 you get more than 15 characters per inch, so I am not sure if the specs are all that well stated.  (To be conservative, or to make calculation easier, I suppose by 2.5 cm we can assume they meant one inch.) A related article is [6 lines per inch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23824/10827).

Comment: If you measure the characters as a list of a's you get 75.00023pt which for all practical purposes an inch. If you want to make it more tight measure them as a list of "l" which is about 41pt and shows the futility of the spec:) With a font size 10 you are complying.

Comment: Did they specify paper size/orientation? If not, use A3 landscape. :-)

Comment: @lockstep Or send them a papyrus and let them figure it out. But seriously, on 11 pt font I get more than 16 characters per inch on a "random" line. I wonder if there is a fixed width font that matches the given specs. I guess I will go with Yiannis advice, they won't notice.

Comment: The specs are contradictory: if they want Computer Modern, they *know* how many characters per inch (on average) are produced.

Comment: @Maesumi Would you please answer with your own comment or with how you solved the problem, so that we can consider closed the question?

Comment: I finally went with the font size of 11, to be on the safe side. I believe even at 11 you get more than 15 characters in 2.5 cm. But you do get less than 6 lines. I will know in 6 months if this creates a problem.  This question can be closed.